view all data in the table without pagination
I was using datatable component from shadcn-ui library and it uses tanstack table to build it and this library shows only 10 rows data even if there are more than 10 data, it only shows  all the data if there is pagination elements.
so, my question is; is there any other way or method I can show all the data without using pagination?
this is the datatable component
import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { DataTablePagination } from "./DataTablePagination";

interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
  withPagination: boolean;
}

export function DataTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
  withPagination,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
  });
// console.log(data);
// {console.log(table.getRowModel().rows?.length)}
  return (
    <div className={`space-y-4  `}>
      <div className="rounded-md border overflow-y-auto h-[415px] border-none">
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <TableHead
                      key={header.id}
                      className={`sticky top-0 bg-blue-600 dark:bg-dark-purple text-white`}
                    >
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell
                  colSpan={columns.length}
                  className="h-24 text-center"
                >
                  No results.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
      {withPagination && <DataTablePagination table={table} />}
    </div>
  );
}


DataTablePagination
import {
  ChevronLeftIcon,
  ChevronRightIcon,
  DoubleArrowLeftIcon,
  DoubleArrowRightIcon,
} from "@radix-ui/react-icons";
import { Table } from "@tanstack/react-table";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface DataTablePaginationProps<TData> {
  table: Table<TData>;
}

export function DataTablePagination<TData>({
  table,
}: DataTablePaginationProps<TData>) {
  const [selectedPageSize, setSelectedPageSize] = useState(5);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Set initial page size to 5
    table.setPageSize(5);
  }, [table]); // Run once when table instance changes

  // ... rest of your component code

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between px-2">
      {/* <div className="flex-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
        {table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length} of{" "}
        {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length} row(s) selected.
      </div> */}
      <div></div>
      <div className="flex items-center space-x-6 lg:space-x-8">
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
          <p className="text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
          <Select
            //   value={`${table.getState().pagination.pageSize}`}
            value={`${selectedPageSize}`}
            onValueChange={(value) => {
              setSelectedPageSize(Number(value)); // Update local state
              table.setPageSize(Number(value)); // Update table state
              // table.setPageSize(Number(value))
            }}
          >
            <SelectTrigger className="h-8 w-[70px] dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white">
              <SelectValue placeholder={table.getState().pagination.pageSize} />
            </SelectTrigger>
            <SelectContent side="top">
              {[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map((pageSize) => (
                <SelectItem key={pageSize} value={`${pageSize}`}>
                  {pageSize}
                </SelectItem>
              ))}
            </SelectContent>
          </Select>
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-[100px] items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium">
          Page {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1} of{" "}
          {table.getPageCount()}
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-2 dark:text-white">
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            className="hidden h-8 w-8 p-0 lg:flex "
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(0)}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Go to first page</span>
            <DoubleArrowLeftIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            className="h-8 w-8 p-0"
            onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Go to previous page</span>
            <ChevronLeftIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            className="h-8 w-8 p-0"
            onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Go to next page</span>
            <ChevronRightIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            className="hidden h-8 w-8 p-0 lg:flex"
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(table.getPageCount() - 1)}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Go to last page</span>
            <DoubleArrowRightIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


here is how the columns definition could be

Please edit the question to include a [mre]. Presumably a table-generating function that paginates will accept a parameter to control the number of rows per page.

@jsejcksn I have updated it, Thanks in advance.

The pagination section of the documentation at the first link in your question includes a link to the TanStack Table v8 Pagination APIs which includes configuration options like manualPagination, rowCount, etc. Do none of those lead to the desired result?

it might be late but I found this solution that works for me.
pass manualPagination as true and that’s it.
due to the manualPagination it showcase all the data that we pass and thus showing all the data together then you can add scroll to the table.
for scroll you can visit this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099679/16695963
